# Nagios: getting a different response on web interface than running the command manually

Tags: mysql, ssl, nagios

I enabled SSL on MySQL this morning, and everything's working fine... except Nagios. The web interface complains that there's an "SSL Connection Error" when testing MySQL, but running the command from the shell, it works fine, give ms all the data it did before SSL was enabled.

I can't seem to replicate the SSL connection error from the shell, which is making it difficult to fix.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a screenshot (redacted of any personal info) and the output from the command line?

Comment: In the webadmin, go to the configuration menu and lookup the commands. What is run for your check_mysql command? Did you replicate that exact command when running it on the command line? Also, what Nagios version do you have. I've had several problems with the one in Debian 6 when it comes to SSL, mostly related to certificate errors, though.

Comment: I'll get a screenshot when I'm at work tomorrow... I ran the exact command, as I turned on debug mode to 2048 to see it run the macros in the log. Cut and paste, and it worked just fine. As for version... in the morning. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I'd managed to remove read access to the client SSL cert from the nagios client. When I ran the command to test it, the user I was running it as DID have read access, and that's why it worked. Once I gave the nagios user read access to the .pem, it all started working properly.

Thanks for the assistance, everyone.

Comment: This is why you have to test manually as the nagios user.